# What's wrong with my scheduled task?

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I've created a scheduled task that dumps data to a location on another server running it under my domain account.  Unfortunately my password on my account periodically changes, so I therefore have to update the password on the task.
However, whilst I was on leave, my account was disabled because the password wasn't reset and the task failed as a result.
When I change the task to use the LOCAL SERVICE account and run it, there are no errors in the history, but it didn't work.  No data is dumped to the location specified in the program.
Strangely though, there is another task that runs using LOCAL SERVICE.

So, why does one task run successfully using LOCAL SERVICE, but the other doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  It was a permissions issue.